# Matplotlib + wxPython - How to pass custom event as a matplotlib event?

Tags: python, events, matplotlib, wxpython

I'm currently trying to implement custom multitouch events into my code. My current code is modularised and separated into three files (Main.py, Panel1.py, Panel2.py) for example here is a minimal working example:

Panel1.py

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import wx
import numpy as np

class Panel1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)

        t = np.arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

        self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.onHover)

    def onHover(self, event):

        x1 = event.xdata
        y1 = event.ydata

        if event.inaxes == self.axes:
            print "Browsing in Panel 1"
```

Panel2.py

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import wx
import numpy as np

class Panel2(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)

        t = np.arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = np.cos(2 * np.pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

        self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.onHover)

    def onHover(self, event):

        x1 = event.xdata
        y1 = event.ydata

        if event.inaxes == self.axes:
            print "Browsing in Panel 2"
```

Main.py

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import wx
import numpy as np

import Panel1 as FirstPanel
import Panel2 as SecondPanel

#MultiTouchHoverEvent, EVT_MULTITOUCH_HOVER = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Main Frame", size=(600, 600))
        self.SetBackgroundColour('white')

        self.panel_size = (10,10)

        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):

        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(10, 10)

        self.Panel1 = FirstPanel.Panel1(self)
        sizer.Add(self.Panel1, flag=wx.EXPAND, pos=(0, 0), span=(1, 1))

        self.Panel2 = SecondPanel.Panel2(self)
        sizer.Add(self.Panel2, flag=wx.EXPAND, pos=(0, 1), span=(1, 1))

        sizer.AddGrowableCol(0)
        sizer.AddGrowableCol(1)

        sizer.AddGrowableRow(0)


        #self.Bind(EVT_MULTITOUCH_HOVER, self.multitouch_handler)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App(False) 
    MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Now I have created this custom event `EVT_MULTITOUCH_HOVER` as you can see commented out in the *Main.py* code. I can bind it to the frame and it works successfully when combined with my multitouch code. However, what I would like to do is to instead have the `EVT_MULTITOUCH_HOVER` override the matplotlib `'motion_notify_event'`. This way I can specify the appropriate action to take for each panel separately within the `onHover` function for each panel

```
(Panel1.py, Panel2.py)
```

I'm not sure if i've explained this very well, so please ask if you have any questions.

The custom event could be anything, it doesn't have to be a multitouch event as in my example. However, for completeness, with regards to the multitouch code, I use pytuio and I run a tuio server named tongseng in the background which sends the interaction with the multitouch trackpad on my mac across the tuio protocol. Then I have a class which I have created which runs a separate thread, constantly listening for tuio events, which then processes the information and calls `wx.PostEvent` for the appropriate custom event (*hover, double click, mouse release etc*).